# Newsletter mail is not been sending to subscribers in Magento 2.1.6

Tags: magento2.1.6

I'm using magento 2.1.6 .The Newsletter mail is not been sending to subscribers.
Have successfully added template to the queue.But the mail is not been sent to the subscribers even after the Queue Date start time.Im using Siteground as server and following Indian standard time.[image]